# how to display 2 tables from mysql in visual studio 17

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

this is in my controller

```
 string connStr = "server=" + IpAddress + ";user=" + UserName + ";database=" + DatabaseName + ";port=" + PortNumber + ";password=" + Password + ";SslMode=none;";
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
 conn.Open();
 string query = " select * from Cities,Regions";
 MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
 DataTable ds = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(ds);
 conn.Close();
```

I use a view model for displaying data from mysql and i fill them as below.

```
 List<Models.ViewModels.city> CT = new List<Models.ViewModels.city>();
 SftpClient sftpclient = new SftpClient("port", "root", "name");
 sftpclient.Connect();

 foreach (DataRow item in ds.Rows)
 {
     city ct = new city
     {
         CityName = item.itemArray[1].ToString(),
         CityNumber = Convert.ToInt32(item.itemArray[2])
     }
     region rg = new region
     {
         RegionName = item.itemArray[1].ToString(),
         RegionNumber = Convert.ToInt32(item.itemArray[2])
     }
 }
 CT.Add(ct);
 return View(CT.ToList());
```

How  could i show regions in my razor. i already used viewbag for sending a list form my region viewmodel. but it doesn't fill the viewmodel obviously but how should i fill the region viewmodel

Comment: You should create/design your view model class structure based on whatever data you need in your razor view. If your view needs to display a list of Cities and List of Regions, have a view model which has those 2 properties.

Comment: i created a viewmodel call CityRegionViewModel and hast list of regions and cities. now i had another problem. how could i fill them with itemArray.  CityRegionViewModel CR = new CityRegionViewModel();   but how to fill CR.Citites?